# Showing that, for all polynomial $p(x)$ with $\deg(p)>1$ the series $\sum 1/p(n)$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, convergence-divergence

How can I show that, for all polynomial $p(x)$ with $\deg(p)>1$, the series $\sum 1/p(n)$ converges? I tried comparison, but it works only for polynomials in $\mathbb{N}[x]$.

Comment: Of course, you are making the assumption that the denominator never gets zero for any $n$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\deg p = \alpha$. There exists an $N,C>0$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $p(n) \geq Cn^\alpha$. (If this is not obvious, try to prove it for yourself!) Then try the comparison test again.

Comment: Okay, it works! Thanks.